Vue Testing: Triggering Checkbox not working
I'm trying to test if a checkbox has been checked with Vue test utils and Vitest, but the test always fails and I don't understand why.
Component.vue:
<template>
    <input type="checkbox" @change="check($event.target.checked)">
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    data() {
        return {
            selected: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        check(checked) {
            console.log(checked)
            this.selected = checked
        }
    }
  }
  </script>

component.spec.js:
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Component from '.././src/components/Component.vue'
import { expect, test } from 'vitest'
import { nextTick } from 'vue'

test('props', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Component)
    await wrapper.find("input[type='checkbox']").trigger("change")
    await nextTick()
    expect(wrapper.vm.selected).toBe(true)
})

The test output is always:
 FAIL  test/component.spec.js > checkbox
AssertionError: expected false to be true // Object.is equality

- Expected
+ Received

- true
+ false

 ❯ test/component.spec.js:10:33
      8|     await wrapper.find("input[type='checkbox']").trigger("change")
      9|     await nextTick()
     10|     expect(wrapper.vm.selected).toBe(true)
       |                                 ^
     11| })

I have already asked AI, and also looked here on StackOverflow. Although there were a lot of similar problems, none of the suggestions worked.
Can someone please explain to me what the problem is and how to resolve it? Thank you in advance.

"checked" won't change if you trigger "change" directly

@EstusFlask What are you suggesting?

Try click() instead, this is what happens with normal user interaction. Vitest uses JSDOM that doesn't work like real DOM in countless ways, I don't remember if that's the case

Thanks to Estus Flask (see comments under the question) I found the solution. I changed the @change in the Vue component to @click.
The modified Component.vue:
<template>
    <input type="checkbox" @click="this.selected = $event.target.checked">
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    data() {
        return {
            selected: false
        }
    },
  }
  </script>

The modified component.spec.js:
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Component from '.././src/components/Component.vue'
import { expect, test } from 'vitest'

test('checkbox', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Component)
    const checkbox = wrapper.find("input[type='checkbox']")
    await checkbox.trigger("click")
    expect(wrapper.vm.selected).toBe(true)
})

